# Function name resolution in base class

Tags: c++

Consider the following code snippet,

```cpp
#include <memory>

template <typename Derived>
class Base
{
public:
    int foo()
    {
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->bar(); // I expected a compilation error here
    }

private:
    int bar()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {};

int baz()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<Derived>()->foo();
}
```

From my understanding, the template class `Base` declares the function `bar` as private and is hence not visible to even `Derived` class, let alone the users of any `Derived` object.

In the public function `foo` of the template class Base, I try to access a non-existing function `bar` through a `Derived` object. I expected the compiler to fail to find the function `bar`.

**Q. How does the compiler find the private `bar` function of the `Base` template class through the use of a `Derived` object?** https://godbolt.org/z/jVxW-k

Now consider a slight variation to the snippet in which the `Derived` class is no longer empty.

```cpp
class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
private:
    int bar()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Here, the output is expected with the compiler erroring out with the message,

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'int Base<Derived>::foo() [with Derived = Derived]':

<source>:30:44:   required from here

<source>:9:49: error: 'int Derived::bar()' is private within this context

    9 |         return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->bar();

      |                                                 ^

<source>:22:9: note: declared private here

   22 |     int bar()

      |         ^~~

Compiler returned: 1
```

**Q. Why wasn't the compiler able to find the private function `bar` now? Is there some way in which I can force Derived implementations to implement the function `bar`?** https://godbolt.org/z/PrkNo6

Compiler used: g++ 9.2.
Compiler flags used: `-std=c++17 -O3 -Wall -Werror`.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Isn't this an implementation of CRTP ??

Comment: @DumbCoder Yes, you're right. I am using the CRTP idiom.

Comment: @Slava because it is accessing through an object of Derived static type. If it was simply a call to `bar` without any `static_cast` it wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: So in first case `Base::foo()` can access `Base::bar()` but in the second case it cannot access `Derived::foo()` and you are asking why?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't the first case `foo` accessing `Derived::bar`? I say this because what do you expect the `decltype(static_cast<Derived*>(this))` to be? Base* or Derived*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q. How does the compiler find the private bar function of the Base template class through the use of a Derived object?

For

```
return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->bar();
```

`Derived` has no `bar`,
looking in base class founds `Base::bar`.

We are in `Base` scope, so we have access to `Base::bar` (even if applied to other type)

> Q. Why wasn't the compiler able to find the private function bar now? Is there some way in which I can force Derived implementations to implement the function bar?

Now, `Derived` has a `bar`, stopping the look-up.

but `Derived::bar` is private in `Base`'s scope (even if applied to `Derived` instance).

Answer (score 2):

Since `Derived` is inheriting from `Base`, when you do `static_cast<Derived*>(this)->bar()` and `bar()` is not implemented in `Derived`, the lookup goes to the base class. As you are using the function within the `Base` class, the private specifier is fine.

When you define a `Derived::bar()` and call it from `Base`, it is private and cannot be accessed outside the `Derived` class